# Google spreadsheet trigger for hiding and showing row

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

Currently, I use onEdit and it is being called when I change values in a cell or range of cells, or when deleting, inserting rows/columns.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Browser.msgBox('edit: ' + (e.range && e.range.getA1Notation()));
}
```

The onEdit function is not being called when hiding or showing a row through the UI.

Is there a way to get my script to be notified of a hide/show row event?

*Update: I wrote a feature request for this in google-apps-script-issues:*
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4670

*Update: As per Kriggs answer, the installable trigger onChange can be used*

Here's how that works.
[image]

However, on the e (event) object, there's no range property from which to see what row/range was hidden or shown. Also Krigg's suggested `Row` method does not exist on `e.source`.

How can we leverage onChange to also get the row number(s) hidden or shown?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out about [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()), which handles specifically changes to structure in the Sheet, and aparently must be activated in the Trigger menu and then choosing a function. To know the ROW you can use just as onEdit(), `e.source.Row();`.

I tested a little bit and found it to be as erratic as time based and onEdit(), out of 3 consecutives hiding only 1 was Logged.

Comment: Yes, this is triggered by hiding and showing rows. But the `Row` method does not exist on `e.source`. I will update my question with more details.